# How can I create a trigger that prevents column delete, data deletion and table truncate in the same time?

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-sql-developer, ddl-trigger

Having written this trigger create:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROTECT_DB BEFORE DROP OR TRUNCATE ON X.SCHEMA
```

How can I "add" a `DELETE` in the trigger definition ? (the `DELETE` should prevent data deleting from tables and column erasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm). In the syntax diagrams note, that there is no way from the `ddl_event/OR` loop to get to `dml_event_clause`.

And it wouldn't make any sense either. On what table should that trigger fire? DDL trigger don't have tables as targets.

Use two separate triggers.

Comment: Could a compound trigger be the solution for this situation ?

Comment: @Skyp89: As far as I understand compound triggers are DML only, combining the event timing (before/after) and scope (row/statement). You're trying to combine DDL and DML triggers. That's another level.